# GoogleSignIn - Always return "The user canceled the sign-in flow." in IOS 11

Tags: swift, xcode, ios11, google-signin

I try to use GoogleSignIn in my project, but I have problem when call `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()`

I received warning below:

```
[Warning] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<SFAuthenticationViewController: 0x7fccba008c00>)
```

And in "GIDSignInDelegate", always had error "The user canceled the sign-in flow."

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {}
```

I searched on somewhere but could not got any solutions for this case, thanks for reading, I hope you will help me :((

UPDATE 1: add GIDSignInUIDelegate implementation

```
extension MyClass: GIDSignInUIDelegate {
    func sign(inWillDispatch signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: Error!) {

        print(#function)
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!) {
        print(#function)
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
        print(#function)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and I received message below:

```
[Warning] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<SFAuthenticationViewController: 0x103023800>)
```

UPDATE 2: Some time alert (in image blow) is shown, then I tap on cancel and it can not shown again [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49REr.jpg)

Comment: do you use `GIDSignInUIDelegate` ?

Comment: Yes, I did, I edited my question.

Comment: Not sure if related, but I actually have to sign in twice in order to get the actual token. Worth a try.

Answer (score 5):

if you use `GIDSignInButton`, replace it with the system's `UIButton`. It works for me.

Comment: This works for Swift 5.3/Xcode 12 in 2020. Is this really the most optimal solution? What if I want to keep the default look and feel of Google Sign In

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. The `GIDSignInButton` object don't need `addTarget` in code or linking `@IBAction`. The `GIDSignInButton` class already handled that action for us.