# How to fix `The user canceled the sign-in flow.` with Sign In with Google on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I am integrating Sign in with Google with iOS Firebase SDK. When a user taps on the `GIDSignIn` button, the app shows an alert showing `"MyAPP" want to use Google.com for Sign in`, but the alert dismisses quickly. The error I get in the `didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser` method as follows:

```
2019-02-21 16:54:13.104279+0530 MyApp[18743:185089] [Warning] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<SFAuthenticationViewController: 0x7fa327945800>)
[DEBUG] Google sign-in error: Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-5 "The user canceled the sign-in flow." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The user canceled the sign-in flow.}
```

I have followed the [Authenticate Using Google Sign-In on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin) documentation.

I also tried the answer at [Google Sign-In crashes on iOS 9 attempting to call canOpenURL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31506866/10900045), but it is not working.

The `AppDelegate` implements `GIDSignInUIDelegate` as well.

If I change the button from [`GIDSignInButton` to `UIButton`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52152137/10900045), it works, but the style is lost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also faced the issue before. The `GIDSignInButton` object don't need `addTarget` in code or linking `@IBAction`. The `GIDSignInButton` class already handle that action for us.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to run `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()` in `@IBAction`. You can run `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self` just before signIn function instead of inside `viewDidLoad()`.

```
@IBAction func googleLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In `Appdelegate` try using the below code

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    let result = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                    sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                    annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    return result

}
```